# Get the (several) EditText values from list view and post as an array

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am developing an android application in which a user gets a json data from the server and put it in list view.

In List view, each Item has some textViews and EditText. Now I want the user to input a number in EditTexts and send the values back to server.

Order.Java:

```
public class Order extends ListActivity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    SessionManager session;
    TextView text;
    private static final String URL = "http://mydomain.in/webservice/json_sas.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_ITEM = "Item";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_SALE = "sale";

    private JSONArray mComments = null;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;
    private JSONArray sasTotal = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
        new LoadOrderForm().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves recent products data from the server.
     */
    public void updateJSONdata() {
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        String cc = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_CC);
        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cc", cc));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);

        try {
            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag
                String item = c.getString(TAG_ITEM);
                String pack = c.getString(TAG_PACK);
                String bal = c.getString(TAG_BAL);
                String sale = c.getString(TAG_SALE);
                String LM1 = c.getString(TAG_LM1);
                String LM2 = c.getString(TAG_LM2);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_ITEM, item);
                map.put(TAG_PACK, pack);
                map.put(TAG_BAL, bal);
                map.put(TAG_SALE, sale);
                map.put(TAG_LM1, LM1);
                map.put(TAG_LM2, LM2);
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mCommentList.add(map);
            }
            sasTotal = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SASARRAY);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < sasTotal.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject d = sasTotal.getJSONObject(i);
                // gets the content of each tag
                String sval = d.getString(TAG_SVAL);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
            R.layout.single_post_order, new String[] { TAG_ITEM,
            TAG_SALE,TAG_BAL }, new int[] { R.id.Item, R.id.sale, R.id.stk });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            }
        }); 
    }

    public class LoadOrderForm extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            updateJSONdata();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            updateList();
        }
    }
}
}
```

ListActivity looks like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-FxbI1t7ezMzVoUWo3NXBlWW8/edit?usp=sharing

Now I would like to learn:

1. How can I detect that user has entered numbers in EditTexts of many Items?
2. How can I collect the id or name from texview and Qty entered in Edittext?
3. How can I post them back to my the server as an ARRAY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just had to do this for a previous project. Hopefully I can give you some insightful answers to your question.

1) You need create your own adapter class and expand it like so.

2) Expand you editview to also look at the id of the textview in your list like so. I'm assuming that you also have a button with this view.

3) Pass the server object into your init function and reference it's methods when the button it clicked.

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

...
    private final ServerClass server;
    private Button submit;

public MyAdapter(Context context,
        List<? extends HashMap<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to, ServerClass server, Button submit) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);

            this.server = server;
            this.submit = submit;
            /*set up all of your init stuff here so you can figure out which view was changed when getview is called*/

}

public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final View mView = super.getView(position, v, parent);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++){
                View row = parent.getChildAt(i);
                View textview= row.findViewById(/*textviewID*/);
                View editview= row.findViewById(/*editviewID*/);
                Log.i("CustomText!!!",textview.getText());
                Log.i("CustomText!!!",editview.getText());
                server.sendPOSTMethod(textview.getText(),editview.getText());
            }
        }
    });

    return mView;
}
```

Comment: Please see the image....https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-FxbI1t7ezMzVoUWo3NXBlWW8/edit?usp=sharing     User types the qty in the edit text fileds then when he click submit button (not shown in pic) it has to collect the data(all id,editText values) from each row and make an array.

Comment: Okay... Then send the button object into the constructor and cycle through the views when it is clicked. I will edit the answer for you. Dont forget to accept